# How to print table of 12 using recursion, I want it upto 10 but on running it turns out to be upto 12

Tags: c++, recursion

I was trying to create a program to print table of 12 using recursion as I wrote a simple program for this I did get table, but table was instead upto 144 (**12times12=144**) instead of 120(**12times10=120**) I am sharing my code and output with you guys I was writing code in C++

```
//we will print table of 12 using concept of recursion
//a table of 12 is like this 
//12 24 36 48 60 72 84 96 108 120
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void table(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        cout<<12<<"\n";
        return;
    }
   
    table(n-1);
    cout<<n*12<<"\n";
}
int main(void)
{
    table(12);
}
```

and now here is out put of this program

```
12
24
36
48
60
72
84
96
108
120
132
144
```

please help me what I'm missing here I am positive that adding some condition will help I tried one adding `if(n==12) { return;}` but it prevents does nothing as in the end it is return `n*12`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want it to print 12, 24, ..., 120, yeah? If so, I think all you have to do is change your call of `table(12)` to `table(10)`.

Comment: For every function you write, you should have comments documenting how that function is to be used. Specify the meaning of each parameter. Test the function in isolation to make sure it conforms to your documentation. In this case, what does `n` represent? How should it affect the functionality of `table()`? Once you have good documentation, you can then ask yourself why you are telling `table` to print multiples (of twelve) up to 12, when you only want them up to 10.

Comment: Very very Thankyou @Shaavin and it worked.

Comment: very nice observation @JaMiT I will definitely add documentation as it will be helpful for me in future  thank you so much for your kind advice 